# Geany custom command not working

Tags: python, command, ubuntu-14.04, geany

I have following code as custom python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
from sys import stdin

sys.stdout.write(DOC_FILENAME)
```

How can I use this as custom command in Geany to get current document name and path ?

Is "geanypy" needed to be installed to run this command ?

Comment: You need to get DOC_FILENAME into your script as e.g. parameter. Than you can use it with Geany. So first step would be to fix your custom script.

Comment: Ohh, I thought `DOC_FILENAME` is a global constant available throughout "Geany environment". Can you suggest how can I fix my script ?

Comment: Check for command line arguments on python. Having this, you can define your custom command e.g. with my_script.py %f